# Sync messages between Facebook and Windows 7

Tags: gratis, windows-7, offline, facebook

I need a program that syncs Facebook messages to my PC.

In Windows 8(.1) you have the Mail app with which you can easily read your emails. It also notifies you when new emails come in and it downloads your emails.

I need a program that does the same, but with Facebook messages (and Windows 7).

Very important to me is that the program makes an offline copy of my messages inbox, which I can read even when they are deleted on Facebook itself.

Is there a program that can do this? And if there isn't, could anyone suggest another way to get notified of new messages?

Comment: I know facebook chat is basically jabber - I've no clue how people who you arn't friends with are handled though

Comment: @JourneymanGeek what you mean ?

Comment: @TomJ You can chat with people who you are friends with, but also with people who aren't your friends.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Did facebook chat keeps an offline copy of messages even if it is deleted from facebook ?

Answer (score 5):

Facebook chat is basically XMPP - any jabber client which has logs like pidgin would log any conversation you had using it (facebook chat is dead, and was a HTML5 'application' which had no logs). An XMPP client as such would be a drop in replacement for FB chat on the desktop- many even have server settings pre-installed for your use.

This has a few advantages - it keeps logs of *everything* even what you've deleted from facebook, and a few disadvantages such as you need to use a specific system or systems for logging.

You could also periodically download a [datadump from facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/405183566203254) that contains undeleted inbox messages. This includes *anything* you have said from a XMPP client to someone else on facebook.

There dosen't seem to be a way to retrieve things you have deleted.

Comment: Can you suggest me a link to download Facebook Chat for Windows ?

Comment: I have it installed, it dosen't work. So no. Anything you said on facebook chat and wasn't deleted *should* be on said datadump

Comment: So in that case, can you help me in some other ways ?

Comment: My answer covers it. The data dump contains *a full log* of everything that you've said on facebook chat. You can switch to *any other jabber client* as an alternative to facebook chat.

Comment: Ok then. How can I access the data dump ?

Comment: "To download your information, go to your Settings and click Download a copy of your Facebook data." <-- it says so, right near the top of the page.