# Chat application for Ubuntu

Tags: gratis, linux, ubuntu, chat, facebook

I need a chat application other than Empathy and Pidgin for my Ubuntu 14.04. I used both and don't like them at all.

So I need a new IM and its specifications are -

- It should support facebook
- It must be fast
- It should be easy to use
- It must show previous chats(for example- Facebook Messenger. It shows all the conversation from the beginning)
- It should support the Facebook stickers(Pidgin is not doing this. So I removed it)

So is there a good IM that supports my needs ?

Comment: Will you be solely be using this app? I can't think of anything that will sync a conversation that happened on facebook.

Comment: At the risk of trolling, aren't there requirements  what _<insert non-Facebook messaging platform here>_ does better anyway?

Comment: Facebook is XMPP, as I told the OP previously. I'm a *little* confused by what he means by pidgin being slow since I've personally never had issues with it.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek What is XMPP ? Is it possible to view recent chat sessions(previous conversations) in Pidgin ?

Comment: XMPP = jabber = the protocol facebook uses. And I think you'd want to read the comments to my answer to this [question again](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/4245/125), where I've covered it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Ubuntu for years and what you are looking for has always been a weak spot in Ubuntu. I have never found anything that would work for chat's. Even skype has it's problems. It is something that I hope the Ubuntu team fixes, but for now I would have to say that the answer to your question is no there isn't.